# Transition superseded, prevented, aborted and failed Angular UI-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using [boilerplate](https://github.com/yannickglt/angular-webpack-boilerplate) to get started with angular. So far I created an additional page basically identical to the existing /home page.

Here is my route in `app.js`:

```
.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('about', {
      name: 'about',
      url: '/about', 
      template: './pages/about/about'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

`/about` currently renders a blank page. And by doing the following changes to my `app.js` file:

```
      templateUrl: './pages/about/about.html',
```

I get a 404 response. I basically need help adding additional routes to the current application, regardless of content. A code example would be much appreciated.

This is the code for the already existing home page:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import HomeController from './home.controller';
import HomeTemplate from './home.template.html';

// Directives
import FooBar from '../../components/foo-bar/foo-bar.component';

angular
  .module('app.home', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(($stateProvider) => {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
          app: {
            template: HomeTemplate,
            controller: HomeController,
            controllerAs: 'home'
          }
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: "superseded, prevented, aborted and failed" - do you mean the transition does not succeed? That could be because you need to specify the path to template as a templateUrl field not template. And I believe it should look something like '/pages/about/about.html'

Comment: I have tried with the suggestions you've mentioned but with no luck.

Comment: I might be wrong with the exact path ('/pages/about/about.html' or 'src/pages/about/about.html'), but it definitely needs to be be put into templateUrl